# Rock Paper Scissors won't print winning condition

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a Rock-Paper Scissors game to practice JavaScript, however, it will not display "Player 1 Wins" if Player 1 is victorious. Instead it will print undefined. I've already gone through the different if and switch cases however, I still can't find the problem.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Here is my  code:

```js
const player1 = document.getElementById("name");
var player2; //if there's a second player 
var choice2; //holds the choice of the second player or the computer
var difficulty;

function getUserInfo() {
  var diff = document.getElementById("difficulty");
  difficulty = diff.options[diff.selectedIndex].value;
  difficulty = parseInt(difficulty);
  var col = document.getElementById("colour");
  var colour = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
}

function compChoice() {
  switch (difficulty) {
    case 1:
      easy();
      break;
    case 2:
      med();
      break;
    case 3:
      hard();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function easy() {
  if (playerChoice == "Rock") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    console.log(choice2);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Paper") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Scissor") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

function med() {
  choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  switch (choice2) {
    case 1:
      choice2 = "Rock";
      break;
    case 2:
      choice2 = "Paper";
      break;
    case 3:
      choice2 = "Scissor";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function hard() {
  if (playerChoice == "Rock") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Paper") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Scissor") {
    choice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    switch (choice2) {
      case 1:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        choice2 = "Rock";
        break;
      case 3:
        choice2 = "Paper";
        break;
      case 4:
        choice2 = "Scissor";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

function comparison() {
  var last_message;
  if (playerChoice === choice2) {
    last_message = "It's a TIE!";
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Rock") {
    switch (choice2) {
      case "Paper":
        last_message = "Player 2 Wins!";
        break;
      case "Scissors":
        last_message = "Player 1 Wins";
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Paper") {
    switch (choice2) {
      case "Scissors":
        last_message = "Player 2 Wins!";
        break;
      case "Rock":
        last_message = "Player 1 Wins";
    }
  }
  if (playerChoice == "Scissors") {
    switch (choice2) {
      case "Rock":
        last_message = "Player 2 Wins!";
        break;
      case "Paper":
        last_message = "Player 1 Wins";
    }
  }
  console.log(last_message);
  document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = last_message;
}

function clearScreen() {
  getUserInfo();
  var playerNumber = 1;
  var x = document.getElementById("input");
  var y = document.getElementById("gameArea");
  x.style.display = "none";
  y.style.display = "block"
  setPlay(playerNumber);
}

function setChoice(playerNumber) {
  var read = document.getElementById("playerSelection");
  playerChoice = read.options[read.selectedIndex].value;
  switch (playerNumber) {
    case 1:
      setPlay(2);
      break;
    case 2:
      compChoice();
      comparison();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function setPlay(playerNumber) {
  document.getElementById("currentPlayer").innerHTML = `Player ${playerNumber}'s turn`;

}
```

```css
#gameArea {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="rps.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="input" onsubmit="return false">
    <label for="name" required>Please enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"><br><br>
    <label for="age" required>Please enter your age</label>
    <input type="text" id="age"><br><br>
    <label for="colour">Please select a colour: </label>
    <select id="colour" required>
      <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="Red">Red</option>
      <option value="Green">Green</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for="">Select your difficulty:</label>
    <select id="difficulty">
      <option value="1">1. Easy</option>
      <option value="2">2. Medium</option>
      <option value="3">3. Hard</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="clearScreen()">
  </form>

  <div id="gameArea">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="currentPlayer"></td>
        <td>
          <select id="playerSelection">
            <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
            <option value="Scissors">Scissors</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><button onclick="setChoice(2)">Submit Choice</button></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>
    <span id="final"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have typos: `case 'Scissors':` should be `case 'Scissor':`

Comment: It's a bad idea that you use `Scissors` for the player's choice, but `Scissor` for the computer's choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comparison function you check for the literal `Scissors` but in you `easy`, `med`, `hard` functions you set choise2 to `Scissor`.
your code is fine you only forgot a letter.

but this code can use some good refactoring after you get it working.

for example if you use ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS as constans you will avoid such problems in the future.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t you forget some `break;` in the comparison switch ?

Comment: You don't need `break` after the last case.

Comment: Saw that snippet on my smartphone, you're so right ;)